# How to raise property changed event when child property changes

Tags: wpf, prism

I have a class with some properties. This class inherit from BindableBase (Prism) for notify properties changes. And another viemodel class that inherit also from BindableBase and has a property of the first class. I have a usercontrol that bind to this properties. This control works well, but when I change one property of the first class, this doesn't propagate the changes to the property of the viewmodel class. Is there a way to make that when I change one property, this fire the property change event in the property of viewmodel class. Thanks.

```
using Prism.Mvvm;
using System.Windows.Media;

// I use this class to bind with the user control
public class FontSetting : BindableBase
{
    private FontFamily fontFamily;
    public FontFamily FontFamily
    {
        get => fontFamily;
        set => SetProperty(ref fontFamily, value);
    }

    private int fontSize;
    public int FontSize
    {
        get => fontSize;
        set => SetProperty(ref fontSize, value);
    }

    private Color textColor = Colors.Black;
    public Color TextColor
    {
        get => textColor;
        set => SetProperty(ref textColor, value);
    }
}

// This class is binding to the window
public class ViewModel : BindableBase
{
    // This property is binding to the user control
    private FontSetting fontSetting = new FontSetting();
    public FontSetting FontSetting
    {
        get => fontSetting;
        set
        {
            var oldValue = fontSetting;
            SetProperty(ref fontSetting, value);
            if (oldValue != value)
            {
                // When I change, for example the FontSize, this doesn't work.
                // But if I check FontSetting.FontSize, this property has changed.
                ChangeProperty(nameof(FontSetting));
            }
        }
    }

    ...

    private void ChangeProperty(string propertyName)
    {
        switch (propertyName)
        {
            case "Text":
                textBlock.Text = Text;
                break;
            case "FontSetting":
                textBlock.FontFamily = FontSetting.FontFamily;
                textBlock.FontSize = FontSetting.FontSize;
                textBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(FontSetting.TextColor);
                break;
            case "BackgroundColor":
                textBlock.Background = new SolidColorBrush(BackgroundColor);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Update:
Solution thanks to [Clemens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1136211/clemens):

```
private FontSetting fontSetting;
public FontSetting FontSetting
{
    get => fontSetting;
    set
    {
        if (fontSetting != value)
        {
            if (fontSetting != null)
            {
                // Clean event handler
                fontSetting.PropertyChanged -= FontSettingChanged;
            }
            fontSetting = value;
            if (fontSetting != null)
            {
                // Set event handler
                fontSetting.PropertyChanged += FontSettingChanged;
            }
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(FontSetting));
        }
    }
}

private void FontSettingChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    ChangeProperty(nameof(FontSetting));
    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(FontSetting));
}
```

Comment: You wouldn't have this problem if you would use data binding instead of manually assigning UI element properties, e.g. `<TextBlock FontSize="{Binding FontSetting.FontSize}" .../>`.

Comment: Are you using data binding? If yes, then where does the textBlock variable come from? Providing your view XAML might help. Also, consider using an underscore to denote private member variables too to help avoid this confusion.

Comment: Hello Clemens. I can't use the binding in textblock because I am using a propertygrid to change the textblock properties and I need to make this changes through the properties of viewmodel class. I upload an image to show why I use this way. Thanks.

Comment: Your ViewModel could attach a PropertyChanged handler, as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35945941/1136211